# Files get deleted when App is uninstalled. DownloadManager Request

Tags: java, android

My Android Application is downloading content to the device.
It doing it well, but when the application get uninstalled all the content get removed, no matter where it saved.

This is my code:

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
    request.setTitle(downloadTitle);request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(locationString, fileName);
    request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);

    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    return manager.enqueue(request);
```

Hope to find solution soon.

Thank you!

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/02/09/changes-downloadmanager-behavior.html

Comment: save your data in internal or external memory not in app cache

Comment: Can you explain please?

Comment: `locationString`. What is the value?

Comment: `no matter where it saved.`. Well where was it saved? Name full paths.

Comment: locationSting is what the user defineds it.. for example "Music/"